# Making Palindrome(if possible) by filling missing characters

Tags: java, palindrome, missing-data

I've been working with a program recently in java which compiles successfully but during execution,after i enter the string, nothing gets displayed, allowing me to type anything on the execution page.The program goes like this:- The user enters a string with a couple of missing letters represented by '.'(a full stop).
The program should fill in those full stops to make a smallest (lexicographically) palindrome word. If this is not possible....display not possible to make a palindrome.  Please tell me if i've gone wrong anywhere. Thank you :)

```js
import java.io.*;
public class JavaApplication {

    static String s;
    
    //main method
     public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        System.out.println("Enter the string with '.' as their missing characters:");
         s=br.readLine();
         int len=s.length();
         String result;
         if(len%2==0){
                    result=even();
                }
                else
          result=odd();
         System.out.println(result);
        
     }
     
   
     //Function to handle odd no. of characters
     static String odd(){
      int len=s.length();
      int mid=(len-1)/2;
      for(int i=1;i<=mid;i++){
       if(s.charAt(mid-i)=='.'||s.charAt(mid+i)=='.'){
                         if(s.charAt(mid)=='.'){
                             s=s.substring(0,mid)+'a'+s.substring(mid+1);
                         }
        if(s.charAt(mid-i)=='.'&&s.charAt(mid+i)=='.'){
         s=s.substring(0,(mid-i))+'a'+s.substring((mid-i)+1,mid)+s.charAt(mid)+s.substring(mid+1,mid+i)+'a'+s.substring((mid+i)+1);
        }
        if(s.charAt(mid-i)=='.'){
         s=s.substring(0,mid-i)+s.charAt(mid+i)+s.substring((mid-i)+1);
        }
        if(s.charAt(mid+i)=='.'){
         s=s.substring(0,(mid+1))+s.charAt(mid-i)+s.substring((mid+1)+1);
        }
       }
         }
      String result=checkPalindrome(); 
      return result;
     }
     
     //Function to handle even no. of characters
     static String even(){
      int len=s.length();
      int mid2=len/2,mid1=mid2-1;
      for(int i=0;i<mid2;i++){
       if(s.charAt(mid1-i)=='.'||s.charAt(mid2+i)=='.'){
        if(s.charAt(mid1-i)=='.'&&s.charAt(mid2+i)=='.'){
         s=s.substring(0,mid1-i)+'a'+s.substring((mid1-i)+1,mid2+i)+'a'+s.substring((mid2+i)+1);
        }
        if(s.charAt(mid1-i)=='.'){
         s=s.substring(0,mid1-i)+s.charAt(mid2+i)+s.substring((mid1-i)+1);
        }
        if(s.charAt(mid2+i)=='.'){
         s=s.substring(0,mid2+i)+s.charAt(mid1-i)+s.substring((mid2+i)+1);
        }
       }
      }
      String result=checkPalindrome(); 
      return result;
     }
     
     
     //Check if s is palindrome
     static String checkPalindrome(){
      String s1=s;
      for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
       char ch=s1.charAt(i);
       s1=ch+s1;
      }
      if(s1.equals(s))
       return s1;
      else{
       s1="cannot form any palindrome";
       return s1;
      }
     }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Your `checkPalindrome()` goes on an infinite loop. You're checking `i < s1.length()`, & inside the loop `s1` seems to only grow further. Hence `i` will never reach `s1.length()`.

Comment: this question is live in codechef.com September long contest and should be closed.

Comment: @Vineet Thank you. I had failed to see that.